# what is cert8.db and key3.db file?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I update the `.Net Framework(4.4 to 4.5)` and `TSL(1.1 to 1.2)` Certificate in my `C#` application.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

> I read somewhere that TSL1.2 run on .Net Framework 4.5 or above.

I also used an upgraded third party library(.dll), after that my application not able to run with normal user privilege. It's always required an administrative privilege.

> I debug my program and check why application required an admin
>   privilege.
>
> I found that my application creates a `cert8.db` and `key3.db` file in the `root directory (c:\)` and for this, it requires an administrative privilege.

How I run my application as a normal user?

Comment: Can you create these files in another folder? For example in app base directory

Comment: I am not creating these file manually. It automatically created. I think this is for changing/upgrading the third party library(DLL).

Answer (score 4):

As you asked for what is **`*.db` Files**, I am giving you some info, hope it helps..

These are called **Trust Database Files (`*.db` Files)**

**`cert8.db`** = ***Stores straightforwardly accessible articles, (for instance, confirmations, support revocation records, and S/MIME records)***

**`key3.db`** = ***Stores the private keys made by the server***

**`secmod.db`** = ***Stores PKCS #11 module setup information***

The mix of these archives is typically called the trust in database, and each record expect a substitute part in securing your Web Server.

The `cert8.db` and `key3.db` records are used to store open and private keys and supports used for engaging secure connection layer (SSL). The `secmod.db` report stores information for engaging and orchestrating additional security modules that can be used with the Web Server, (for instance, hardware accelerator cards).